# Change cron.daily run time on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cron

Am I correct in understanding that to update the time that a daily cron job runs (from `/etc/cron.daily/`), all I need to do is update the `/etc/crontab` file?

Are there any risks I should be aware of when doing this?

My understanding is based on [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on which cron daemon is installed, but typically the daily cronjobs are indeed scheduled from `/etc/crontab`.

The one thing to keep in mind is that typically you'd want to have daily tasks completed before starting the weekly and then the monthly jobs; adjust one, check if you need to adjust the others.

And don't overlook system jobs that are scheduled through `/etc/cron.d/*` and colleagues that have  used `crontab -e` as root to schedule jobs as well.

Comment: Please note that you can't change time of ONE of the daily jobs, only all of them. Only option is to build a call in /etc/cron.d or crontab manually.